# Wrong position of some ornamentations in the book's margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, margins, book-design, decorations

I'm trying to setup some corners ornamentations with the **pgfornament** package.  It works, but the **horizontal position** of some of the ornamentations is wrong and I don't know how to push them properly.  Here's a stripped down MWE version of my full castle of cards, that shows the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}  % Options : [perpage], [symbol], [multiple]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,medium]{titlesec}

% Main header :
\newpagestyle{principal}{
    \sethead[\thepage][][\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}]{\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}}{}{\thepage}
    \headrule
}

% Add a gray border :
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\definecolor{colorMarge}{RGB}{242,242,245}
\newlength{\distance}
\setlength{\distance}{0.0in} % 0.5in
\newlength{\rulethickness}
\setlength{\rulethickness}{0.5in} % 1pt
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{\paperheight} % Longueur de la ligne
\newlength{\xoffset}
\newlength{\yoffset}
\setlength{\yoffset}{0pt} %{0.5\dimexpr\paperheight-\ruleheight}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{1pt}% no additional frame for \colorbox
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\distance}%
    \else
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\rulethickness-\distance}%
    \fi
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{\yoffset}){%
        \colorbox{colorMarge}{\parbox[b][\ruleheight][c]{\rulethickness}{%
        \centering
        \ifodd\value{page}%
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{lightgray}{\strut \large{\normalfont\textsc{Name and year}}}}%
        \else
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{lightgray}{\strut \huge{\normalfont\textsc{Book Title}}}}%
        \fi}}}}%
}

% Add ornementations to corners :
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{2mm}%
    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{\paperwidth-\@tempdima-0.75in}%
    \setlength{\@tempdimc}{\paperheight-\@tempdima}%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdima},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){%
        \pgfornament[anchor=north west,width=0.75in,color=gray]{41}}
        \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdima},\LenToUnit{\@tempdima}){%
        \pgfornament[anchor=south west,width=0.75in,symmetry=h,color=gray]{41}}
        \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){%
        \pgfornament[anchor=north east,width=0.75in,symmetry=v,color=gray]{41}}
        \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdima}){%
        \pgfornament[anchor=south east,width=0.75in,symmetry=c,color=gray]{41}}
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{principal}

\chapter{Chapter title}

Some funny line\footnote{Some weird footnote text.}

\newpage

Another line

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview of what this code is doing (no, it's not hacking the Central Bank of America), and the issue shown in red:

[image]

So I need to fix two things:

1. The ornamentations shouldn't be inside the vertical gray region.  They should be inside the margins, while the gray region (left and right pages) are reserved for some book informations and the pages binding.
2. The ornamentations should be used on all pages, but only for the **main matter part** of the book.  There should be no ornamentations on any of the other pages (**front matter** and **back matter**).

So how could I fix both issues?

Comment: Kinda related: Are you using a fully up to date latex installation? If you are the new format includes new hooks to add stuff to the background. Similar to eso-pic plus the picture package. Meaning you don't need LenToUnit. There also dimexpr so you can do the calculations directly. It should be easy enough to add this to the background hook and then clear your hook after the frontmatter

Comment: @daleif, I’m using TexLive 2015 (can’t upgrade since I work on a big project and don’t want to mess things). I downloaded and hand installed the latest ornaments package.

Comment: Then you have my sympathies. I'm not at a pc so cannot help

Answer (score 2):

Just shift the ornaments in the same way as you did it for the grey margin box.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor, calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\definecolor{colorMarge}{RGB}{242,242,245}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mymargin
\setlength\mymargin{0.5in}
\newlength\mysize
\setlength\mysize{1.5in}
\newlength\mysep
\setlength\mysep{6mm}

\newcommand\mybox[2][]{%
  \colorbox{colorMarge}{%
    \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{%
      \parbox[c][\mymargin][c]{\paperheight}{%
        \centering\color{lightgray}\normalfont #1 #2}}}}

\newcommand\leftornament[1]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1}, \LenToUnit{\mysep}){%
    \pgfornament[anchor=south, width=\mysize, color=gray, symmetry=h]{41}}%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1}, \LenToUnit{\paperheight-\mysep}){%
    \pgfornament[anchor=north, width=\mysize, color=gray]{41}}}

\newcommand\rightornament[1]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1}, \LenToUnit{\mysep}){%
    \pgfornament[anchor=south, width=\mysize, color=gray, symmetry=c]{41}}%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1}, \LenToUnit{\paperheight-\mysep}){%
      \pgfornament[anchor=north, width=\mysize, color=gray,  symmetry=v]{41}}}

\newcommand\allOrnaments{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \put(0,0){\mybox[\scshape\large]{Name and Year}}%
    \leftornament{\mymargin+\mysep}%
    \rightornament{\paperwidth-\mysize-\mysep}%
  \else
    \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth-\mymargin},0){\mybox[\scshape\huge]{Book Title}}%
    \leftornament{\mysep}%
    \rightornament{\paperwidth-\mysize-\mymargin-\mysep}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\startOrnaments{\AddToShipoutPicture{\allOrnaments}}
\newcommand\stopOrnaments{\ClearShipoutPicture}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1-5]
\mainmatter
\startOrnaments
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1-20]
\backmatter
\stopOrnaments
\chapter{The End}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]